# Como eu conseguiria pegar o primeiro dia do Mês anterior?

Tags: postgresql

Primeiramente bom dia pessoal, estou fazendo uma base onde eu gostaria que a partir do mês atual, o usuário conseguiria ver as informações de 3 meses atras, porem estou com dificuldade em conseguir deixar essa data de 3 meses atras fixa no primeiro dia do mês. como eu poderia fazer isso?

Essa é a parte do Código que eu precisaria incluir a função de pegar o primeiro dia:

```
          SELECT ped_cli_id, fnc_total_pedido(ped_id, 'N') AS total
      FROM tb_pedido          
      WHERE ped_data BETWEEN now() - interval '4 months' AND now() - interval '1 months'
```

Desde já agradeço

Comment: só truncar a data pelo mês... `date_trunc('month', now() - interval '4 months')`

Comment: Agora foi, muito obrigado Rovann, agora consigo filtrar tranquilo. Forte abraço...